# How to monitor simple bi-directional TCP socket traffic (Telnet) in the middle of two endpoints?

Tags: tcp, proxy, netcat

I'm debugging an IOT protocol between two essentially black boxes on my local network talking over a telnet connection.  On either end, I can specify the IP address and port.  I'd like to observe / record the data exchanged between the client and server.

I'm thinking a proxy running on my Mac laptop might work. I've done some research and experimentation with `nc` (BSD netcat).  I can only figure out a working one-way pipe, and thus the protocol exchange does not happen between A and B.

```
  Telnet TCP server (A) <===============> TCP Client (B)
  
  
  Telnet TCP server (A) <===\       /==> TCP Client (B)
                             \     /
                              \   /
          Proxy/Intercept (C)   *
```

Using a feature in the server device (A), I can have two telnet connections active.   Using this, I've been able to see the server's (A) responses to whatever Client (B) is commanding, but I cannot see the Client (B) commands.  ~80% of the responses are a code meaning invalid command received, but a few are reasonable responses for what this thing should be doing.  I can also note that that data rate is only about 4 Bytes / second, so I'd be happy to just watch this exchange live in a terminal.

To clarify:  I can power-cycle the client (B), and it will re-establish a socket connection to the IP address and port of my choosing, so I'm not really thinking about a sniffing / Wireshark type solution.

I guess I'm hoping for a relatively straightforward solution run in the shell using existing standard tools.  I suppose a small program could be written in Python or something to do this, but I hope that's overkill.

Comment: It might be a lot easier to get a network capture with wireshark and use the "follow tcp stream" feature. https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowStreamSection.html

Comment: At your encouragement @Jim D, I sorta gave it a go.  I'm not intercepting any TCP traffic between (A) and (B), presumably because the packets are not broadcasting throughout the LAN.

Comment: Either use a cheap hub (rather than a switch), or if you have a managed switch, "span" the port connected to A or B to the port of the machine you want to capture on.  If you are going to try to debug things like this it is definitely worth getting a managed switch to help debug things.